# Play remote mp3 using Song.FromUri

Tags: windows-phone-7, azure-storage

I am trying to play audio files hosted on Azure blob. I serve them up over HTTP (not HTTPS) and I use SoundEffect.Play from a stream I open using web client. This works great with WAV files.

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.OpenReadAsync(uri);
wc.OpenReadCompleted += (s, e) =>
{
    try
    {
        var sfx = SoundEffect.FromStream(e.Result);
        FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
        sfx.Play();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Well, crap!");
    }
};
```

For MP3s, I use this method:

```
var song = Song.FromUri(item.Title, uri);
FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
MediaPlayer.Play(song);
```

It works in the emulator, sometimes, but NOT on a device! I even tried not using Zune to deploy and use WPConnect to deploy the XAP directly to the device (some folks said this made it work)

This is driving me nuts! These mp3 files should just play, right?

Answer (score 0):

Whether you can play an MP3 or not very much depends upon the specifics of that file.
See 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff462087(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_AudioSupport for details of the MP3s that are supported.

Please also note that the codecs supported by devices and the emulator have some differences so there are cases where you can play something in the emulator but not on a device.